# Figure out overtime hours based on a punch in, punch out, puch lunch

Tags: php, mysql

This is my set of data:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
,user_id INT NOT NULL
 ,payroll_id INT NOT NULL
,type CHAR(3) NOT NULL
,time INT NOT NULL
,created INT NOT NULL 
,modified INT NULL 
 ,site_id INT NOT NULL
,is_lunch TINYINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES 
(242144 ,1289 ,0 ,'in'  ,1389020986 ,1389020986 ,1389020986 ,1000 ,0),
(242679 ,1289 ,0 ,'out' ,1389049440 ,1389135896 ,1389194110 ,1000 ,0),
(242777 ,1289 ,0 ,'in'  ,1389106200 ,1389194089 ,1389194137 ,1000 ,0),
(242778 ,1289 ,0 ,'out' ,1389136200 ,1389194092 ,1389194153 ,1000 ,0),
(242779 ,1289 ,0 ,'in'  ,1389194095 ,1389194095 ,1389194095 ,1000 ,0),
(242976 ,1289 ,0 ,'out' ,1389221878 ,1389221878 ,1389221878 ,1000 ,0),
(243062 ,1289 ,0 ,'in'  ,1389280527 ,1389280527 ,1389280527 ,1000 ,0),
(243070 ,1289 ,0 ,'out' ,1389280683 ,1389280683 ,1389280683 ,1000 ,0),
(243071 ,1289 ,0 ,'in'  ,1389280686 ,1389280686 ,1389280686 ,1000 ,0),
(243278 ,1289 ,0 ,'out' ,1389309710 ,1389309710 ,1389309710 ,1000 ,0),
(243361 ,1289 ,0 ,'in'  ,1389365719 ,1389365719 ,1389365719 ,1000 ,0),
(243573 ,1289 ,0 ,'out' ,1389395108 ,1389395108 ,1389395108 ,1000 ,0),
(243700 ,1289 ,0 ,'in'  ,1389626136 ,1389626136 ,1389626136 ,1000 ,0),
(243886 ,1289 ,0 ,'out' ,1389654144 ,1389654144 ,1389654144 ,1000 ,0),
(243998 ,1289 ,0 ,'in'  ,1389713199 ,1389713199 ,1389713199 ,1000 ,0),
(244177 ,1289 ,0 ,'out' ,1389741915 ,1389741915 ,1389741915 ,1000 ,0),
(244254 ,1289 ,0 ,'in'  ,1389797075 ,1389797075 ,1389797075 ,1000 ,0),
(244461 ,1289 ,0 ,'out' ,1389827243 ,1389827243 ,1389827243 ,1000 ,0),
(244545 ,1289 ,0 ,'in'  ,1389883652 ,1389883652 ,1389883652 ,1000 ,0),
(244762 ,1289 ,0 ,'out' ,1389914226 ,1389914226 ,1389914226 ,1000 ,0),
(244830 ,1289 ,0 ,'in'  ,1389968788 ,1389968788 ,1389968788 ,1000 ,0),
(245025 ,1289 ,0 ,'out' ,1389996312 ,1389996312 ,1389996312 ,1000 ,0),
(245214 ,1289 ,0 ,'in'  ,1390232302 ,1390232302 ,1390232302 ,1000 ,0);
```

I would like to figure out the total number of hours worked per week and then subtract that number from 40 to get overtime hours. Broken down by week with week 1 normal hours, week 1 overtime hours, week 2 normal hours, week 2 overtime hours. All through MYSQL. Is it even possible with this data-set?

Time is the time the punch is made. So if your `'type'` is `'in'` your clock has started. The next `'out'` denotes you punched out so you find how much `'time'` happened between the `'in'` and `'out'`.

Comment: Write a query, and then if it doesn't work, submit it so we can help you.

Comment: Everything is possible.

Comment: The part I get hung up on is how to group them. How to know what belongs with what. Going off the in and out and saying this in and this out are together, now find the hours between them.

Comment: The easiest would be to add a second table that holds the hours spent at work day per day. You could maintain that table as you go or batch process it. If you can't add another table, then you can sum all the out's subtract all the in's of a particular day.

Comment: That's what I am thinking as well. A better way to group days and hours worked. This set of data is too broad to properly group and figure out calculations.

Comment: Check out my answer, I think that will work.

Answer (score 1):

You can SUM all the out, and then SUBSTRACT all the in, then group them by day. This is making the assumption that for each in, there is an out on the same day.

To group them by day, you need to use DATE functions to extract the year-month-day out of the timestamps.

Something like:

```
SELECT
    SUM(IF(type = 'in', -1 * time, time)),
    DATE_FORMAT(time, 'some format') AS day
FROM punch
GROUP BY day
```

For the format, see: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Comment: This works but the only issue I will have is if someone does an overnight shift. They punch in at 11pm on 01/20/2014 and then punch out at 2am 01/21/2014. That needs to be calculated but they cannot be grouped because they are in different days. I think I will have to cut my losses and go with a better way of grouping punch times.

Comment: You have to define what a "day" means to you. Is there any time of the day when NOBODY is working? You could define a day starting at 6AM and finishing at 5:59AM. That way, even if someone works from 10PM to 5AM there shift will not span across 2 days, just the one.

Comment: You could group by the starting day, or by the ending day, but that might be troublesome for overnight shifts that start in one week and end in another. How to account for those kinds of hours isn't really a database issue; it's an accounting or business management or contract management issue.

Comment: The time of day people work is variable. Sometimes we have night shifts any day of the week (including weekends). The only concrete start and stop times we have are the first day of the pay week and the last day of the pay week.

Comment: So if someone works a night shift, which day do you count that under?

Comment: Payroll reasons it should count them as 2 different clock ins and out. So it should count from your clock in till the end of that clock in day at 23:59:59. But the system doesnt do that. It just logs when you clock in and out it doesn't automatically kill your clock out at 23:59:59 and clock you back in at 00:00:00.